# Show that two SDE with similar drifts have similar stationary distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Is it true? Suppose

$$ dX_t = \nabla V_1(X_t) + \sqrt{2} dB_t \,,$$
$$ dY_t = \nabla V_2(Y_t) + \sqrt{2} dB_t \,.$$

If $V_1$ and $V_2$ are ``close", would the stationary distributions of $X_t$ and $Y_t$ be close? For example, can we bound the Wasserstein distance $W^2_2(\mu, \nu)$ where $\mu, \nu$ are the stationary distributions of $X_t$ and $Y_t$? Perhaps, by something like $\|V_1 - V_2\|^2_2$, or like $\|\nabla V_1 - \nabla V_2\|^2_2$.

Comment: What information do you have for $\nabla V_{i}$? Are they Lipschitz? are the Vi convex?

Comment: Here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.02750.pdf "An SDE perspective on stochastic convex optimization" they study the limit for such SDEs if you have minus and convexity (take sigma to have a zero column and a ones column).

Comment: @ThomasKojar In the particular case I'm thinking about, I'm comparing the drifts $\nabla V(z_{-i})$ and $\nabla V(z_{-j})$ where the $-i$ subscript denotes removing the $i$th component from $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$. And I suppose $V$ can be convex and smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$\begin{align*}dX_t&=-\nabla V_1(X_t)dt+\sqrt2 dB_t \\ dY_t&=-\nabla V_2(Y_t)dt+\sqrt2 dB_t.\end{align*}$$ It is well-known that under suitable conditions of $V_1,V_2$ (e.g. $\lambda$-convexity), the processes $X,Y$ converge to equilibrium $\mu_1,\mu_2$ resepectively, where $$\begin{align*}\mu_i(dx)&=\frac{\exp(-V_i(x))}{\int\exp(-V_i(y))dy}dx\end{align*}$$

Hence, the densities of the stationary distributions are known. However, in general it is quite difficult to bound the Wasserstein distance of measures in terms of their densities, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4636396/can-we-bound-the-l1-distance-between-densities-by-wasserstein-distance-of-measur/4728720#4728720).

In this particular case, i doubt that a meaningful bound can be achieved as you describe it. Consider the case where $$V_i(x)=\theta_i(x-m_i)^2$$
leading to $\mu_i$ being Gaussian with mean $m_i$ and variance $\theta_i^{-1}$.

Now note that, unless $\theta_1=\theta_2$ as well as $m_1=m_2$ (in which case the Wasserstein distance would be $0$ anyway), we have both $$\Vert V_1-V_2\Vert_2^2=\infty, \hspace{1cm} \Vert \nabla V_1-\nabla V_2\Vert_2^2=\infty.$$
Hence i doubt that one would be able to describe the "similarity" between $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ using such quantities.

Perhaps another approach is the following: One can view the evolution described by the SDEs as a  Gradient Flow of a certain energy functional, namely the relative entropy functional $\text{Ent}_{\mu_i}$, on the Wasserstein space. Perhaps a more promising approach would be to compare $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ by some comparison between $\text{Ent}_{\mu_1}$ and $\text{Ent}_{\mu_2}$. For more information on viewing this problem as a Gradient Flow, see the book [Lectures on Optimal Transport](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-72162-6), specifically Chapter 18.